# $ \int_{0}^{2\pi} \theta e^{-i\pi K \sin(\theta)} d\theta $

Tags: integration, harmonic-analysis, bessel-functions

I am working on a problem that involves solving a specific integral and potentially relating it to Bessel functions. The integral in question is:

$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi} \theta e^{-i\pi K \sin(\theta)} d\theta
$$

where $K$ is a constant. My goal is to solve this integral explicitly, and I suspect that the solution might involve Bessel functions, given the form of the integrand. However, I'm unsure how to proceed, especially in terms of integrating by parts or directly relating this to Bessel functions, such as $J_0$.

From my understanding, Bessel functions often arise in the context of integrals involving oscillatory functions like $e^{iz\sin(\theta)}$, but the presence of the linear term $\theta$ complicates the application of standard methods or direct identification of Bessel function representations.

I have considered integrating by parts, with:

- $u = \theta$, thus $du = d\theta$,
- and $dv = e^{-i\pi K \sin(\theta)} d\theta$,

but I did not arrive at a straightforward path to involve Bessel functions in the solution.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance on how to solve this integral, especially if there's a way to express the solution in terms of Bessel functions or any advice on techniques or transformations that might make solving this integral more tractable. If anyone has insights into approaching this problem or references that might help, I would be very thankful for your assistance.

Thank you in advance for your time and help!

Comment: $ \int_{0}^{2\pi} \theta e^{-i\pi K \sin(\theta)} d\theta = -i\left.\frac d{da}\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{a i\theta-i\pi K \sin(\theta)} d\theta\right|_0$. For $\pi K\in\Bbb Z$, the second integral is a Bessel function, but for other cases, it does not match the [Anger/Weber functions](https://dlmf.nist.gov/11.10) either.